# Why is my computer screen black whenever I load an OS?

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, linux-mint

Whenever I boot up windows I get the "Starting Windows" screen and then I'm shown a black screen with a mouse cursor (which I can move). I installed Linux Mint 17 on an entirely different hard drive and booted it up and was welcomed with a similar screen. I ran Windows Memory Diagnostic and it found no errors. I tried doing a Windows system restore and it could not do it due to a memory error. I got an "IRQL not less or equal blue screen error" at one point (before I was getting the black screen). I assume it's some sort of hardware issue but I don't know what part to replace. Also, when I was installing Linux Mint, the computer was able to run the OS from the disc without any issues.

Comment: Do you have two monitors?

Comment: Can you bring up the task manager by chance?  Can you boot into safe mode?

Comment: I can't boot into safe mode or open task manager. And I have three monitors.

Comment: try only having one of them connected while you do the OS install.   Completely disconnect the other two monitors while doing this.

Comment: Try only using one RAM module to boot your computer. If you have an extremal graphics card (PCI-E, for example) remove it and use your on board graphics to test the black screen symptoms. IRQ errors can usually be RAM, graphics or failing hard disk.

Comment: Running Mint "from the disc" - do you mean the CD disc or the hard disk?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried doing a Windows system restore and it could not do it due to a memory error

What's the exact message that you received, this is a bit vague.

> I got an "IRQL not less or equal blue screen error" at one point (before I was getting the black screen).
>
> I assume it's some sort of hardware issue

Software issues could cause this, so eliminate those first.  Typically there is a driver filename at the bottom of this message that can help identify the hardware.  I doubt you remember that, though.

Note that malware, if it does things on the kernel level, could cause this.

FWIW General hardware issues like an overheating system, bad RAM, a bad powersupply, or a damaged motherboard could cause this.  I had an old 533Mhz Compaq that did this every time I tried to encode an .mp3 using WinLAME.  I never dusted this system in the 3 years I used it and I think it overheated.

> Also, when I was installing Linux Mint, the computer was able to run the OS from the disc without any issues.
>
> I'm shown a black screen with a mouse cursor (which I can move)

Based on these two things, I suspect one of the following:

- Failing hard drive.  Windows is trying to read a file it needs to start and the drive is not cooperating.  You wouldn't see this if you booted and ran an OS from a CD.
- Malware.  Reinstall Windows and see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know your hardware configuration : computer model, motherboard, RAM, disks. It would also help to know the four parameters of the STOP (blue screen).

Since you are getting memory errors, I would reseat the RAM sticks after cleaning the contacts
and ensure that they are compatible and positioned as instructed by the manual.
If you have a mix of RAM sticks, try to use only one kind.

Error [IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms854226.aspx) is described by Microsoft:

> This Stop message indicates that a kernel-mode process or driver
>   attempted to access a memory address to which it did not have
>   permission to access.
>
> This error usually occurs after the installation of a buggy **device driver, system service, or BIOS**.

To treat each of the possible causes :

- BIOS : See if a BIOS update is available. If not, verify all BIOS parameters.
- Device driver :

  - Try to boot Windows in Safe mode. If this works, examine the Event Viewer.
  - Disconnect all possible devices and reboot.
- System service : Try to boot to the Last Known Good Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

More effort is required on your part to properly identify the problem. Let's identify the options:

### Booting

1. **Live-CD.** These are ubiquitous these days, e.g. [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage). You need a working computer to download and burn them, or order prefabricated ones [online](http://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=boot%20cd). The same goes for USB-drives.
2. **Boot from USB.** Puh Edition v2 (of Russian origin) is the best, but might be not available to you. You can try [Android](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/installhowto), [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/), [Linux](http://damnsmalllinux.org/usb.html).
3. Take a working **bootable HDD** from a different computer and attach to your problem computer (presumably, to a SATA port). Boot it. Detach all other HDDs if in doubt. Computers are so cheap these days, some used ones in good working condition come at the price of one meal. You or your friends might already have several unused computers lying around. Laptops take less space (and consume less electricity).

I would say, trying three different operating systems is a good effort. It is just a matter of popping in the respective boot media and poking around a bit in the resulting desktop.

### Checks

1. Run some good **memtest** (e.g. from [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage)) for several hours. All kinds of busmaster devices can cause memory errors, including sound cards, disk controllers and video cards.
2. Get a good grasp on what is your **primary video device**. Disable some of them in BIOS, if it helps. BIOS and DOS normally use only the primary device. By the original description, you might just have a big misconfigured virtual desktop in Windows, looking at the wrong screen (the empty one).
3. Inspect the available devices. Try 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems. In particular, `taskmgr`  (in Windows) or `top` (in Unix) and **BIOS** should see correct amount of **physical memory** and all the attached hard drives. Some OS-specific *device manager* should also see all your display devices.
4. Is there a signal going to all three of your monitors? Most monitors have an onscreen-menu with information describing the **input signal** (resolution, frequency), or go to sleep when receiving the specific *"sleep"* signal from PC.

### Feedback

Describe the symptoms in more detail.

> I can't boot into safe mode or open task manager. And I have three monitors.

1. What happens when you boot the safe mode? Does it lock up? Does it restart repeatedly? Is there a blue screen? Are <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> and <kbd>NUM LOCK</kbd> functioning?
2. In the empty desktop -- can you pop up a menu with the right mouse key? What happens when you press  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>? Is the mouse cursor constrained to the screen borders?
3. What are your three monitors connected to? What signals do they receive during the boot process?
4. How did the various operating systems from Live-CD's behave?

I will edit the answer, if more diagnostics become available.